# How to use AJAX and PHP strpos() function together when clicking on a button and display results

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am working on a web app. This web app should be able to let a user search for a keyword from a text file from your computer and display the line that contains it, the previous line and the line after it. I used PHP file handling for reading the file and save each line in an array of strings which will be used in searching and displaying of results.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="form-search" action = "index.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="keyword" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Keyword</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="keyword" id="keyword" placeholder="Keyword">
            </div>
    </div><!-- end .from-group -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-2">
            <button type="submit" id = "searchkey" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
        </div>
    </div><!-- end .from-group -->
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#form-search').submit(function(event){
        var key = $('#keyword').val();
        var ajaxurl = 'search.php',
        data =  {'action': key};
        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response, status) {

            alert(status);
        });
    });
```

search.php

```
<?php
    if (isset('$_POST['action']')) 
    {
        $keyword = $_POST['action'];
        search($keyword);
    }
    function search($key)
    {
        $x = 0;
        $y = 0;
        $line;
        $myfile = fopen("samplefile.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
        while(!feof($myfile)) 
        {
            $line[$x] = fgets($myfile);
            $x++;
        }
        fclose($myfile);

        while($y<=$x)
        {
            if (strpos($key,$line[$y]) !== false) {
                echo "Before: " . $line[$y-1] . "<br>";
                echo "After: " . $line[$y+1] . "<br>";
                echo "Line " . $y . ": " . $line[$y];
               // break;

            }
            else
                $y++;
        }
        if($y>$x)
        {
            echo "Can't find keyword."
        }

    }

}
?>
```

The code above doesn't do anything when I click the button. I am just not sure what is wrong with it..... And I may not have understand fully $.post() and $_POST. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What output do you get (e.g. a blank page, "Can't find keyword.", page never finishes loading)?

Comment: It does nothing but refreshes current page.

Comment: Well, at least try adding some echo lines or some other debugging technique to figure out which code branches it *is* executing. StackOverflow isn't a "debug my code for me" site, you need to show that you've done as much as you can on your own, then come with a specific question to help you get past wherever you're stuck.